# Know disk space using ssh remotely using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am using following commands to extract the disk space using ssh remotely. but wants to iust store the output instead of all other message as below;

Any help? or any alternative solution?

```
ssh rajesh-server 'df -h /db* | cat' 2>&1

|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |
| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |
| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |
| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |
| personnel.                                                      |
|                                                                 |
| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |
| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |
| of authorized users may also be monitored.                      |
|                                                                 |
| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |
| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |
| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |
| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vx/dsk/xcv01_day/db01_day
                  200G  154G   44G  79% /db01_day
/dev/vx/dsk/xcvg01_day/db01_day
                  200G  154G   44G  79% /db01_day
 /dev/vx/dsk/xcvg01_day/db01_day
                  200G  154G   44G  79% /db01_day
```

Comment: ssh -q rajesh-server 'df -h /db* | cat' 2>&1 solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

All of the text in the "box" is generated by your login scripts, and not by the `df` command.  Often, a server set up with login messages will skip showing you those messages if a file called `.hushlogin` exists in your home directory.  So first off, try creating that file:

```
ssh rajesh-server "touch .hushlogin"
```

Next, you don't need the `| cat` in your command line, OR the stderr redirection most likely.  Try this instead:

```
ssh rajesh-server 'df -h /db*'
```

If you still get the messages with the `.hushlogin` file in place, then you will need to parse your output.  This would do it:

```
ssh rajesh-server 'df -h /db*' | sed '/^|/d'
```

This `sed` command takes in the output of your ssh command, deletes any lines starting with a pipe character, and prints everything else.

Note that you probably want to consider using a monitoring tool that is build specifically for this kind of task.  Many exist, some as [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) front-ends.  My favourites are [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).  These will graph your disk (or network or other) usage so you can see how things change over time.

If you'd like a tool that sends you a warning if you get close to limits, have a look at [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), [Icinga](http://www.icinga.org/) or [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.org/).

Comment: Hi Graham, Thank very much for your useful info. I am trying other tools as you mentioned. But could not get working any of the ssh commands tips. ;(

Comment: No problem, happy to help.  What does "could not get working" mean, exactly?  Do you get errors?  I have a keyboard at home into which I spilled coffee once, so now when I press "s" I get "z".  If you have a similarly damaged keyboard, it would be difficult to run either the "zzh" or "zed" commands...

Comment: I used all adove command and output is coming "|---" etc...no change in output.

Comment: I mean output of all adove commands are same..

Comment: let me add more point is that i am using Linux RHEL

Comment: Then either the comment lines are being sent to stderr, or they are slightly different from what you posted in your question.  Try `ssh rajesh-server 'df -h /db*' 2>/dev/null` instead of the line with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh rajesh-server 'df -h /db*' > file 2> /dev/null
```

sends the remote `df` output to `file` while sending the server's cruft to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I am using some automation. Is it possible to display on command prompt only?